# way to remove comma from format of windows edit control? (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, controls, format, edit

using a windows EDIT control with ES_NUMBER style and with an accompanying UPDOWN control, the default number written to the EDIT control uses a comma in the thousands place. Is there any way to turn off this behavior? 
I tried intercepting a notification from the UPDOWN control and immediately overwriting the text but it looks like either the notification isn't being detected or I'm overwriting the text just before it writes the new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `UDS_NOTHOUSANDS` style to the spin button control.

Comment: Thx. Completely forgot that I'd done this before. I'm starting to think somethings seriously wrong with me.